# React error in console - Maximum update depth exceeded when input length is more than 5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, conditional-statements

I have an input component that accepts input upto 5 characters. When the input length is more that 5, it shows a message `Limit Exceeds (only upto 5 characters accepted)`.

**Sample component code :**

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function ConditionalInput() {

  const [inputInfo, setInputInfo] = useState({ value: "", lengthCount: 0 });
  const [warningMessageVisible, setWarningMessageVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputInfo.value.length > 5) {
      setInputInfo((s) => ({ ...s, lengthCount: 0 }));
    }
  }, [inputInfo, warningMessageVisible]);

  const onChange = ({ target }) => {
    setInputInfo((s) => ({ ...s, value: target.value }));
    if (target.value.length > 5) {
      setWarningMessageVisible(true);
    }
  };
  
  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={inputInfo.value} onChange={onChange} />
      <div>Number of secrets: {inputInfo.lengthCount}</div>
      {warningMessageVisible && (
        <h3>Limit Exceeds (only upto 5 characters accepted)</h3>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

On the UI everything looks ok but in the console I can see an error message printing in an infinite loop stating -  **Maximum update depth exceeded**

[image: Erro message screenshot]

**Note** - Above code is not the actual code I'm using but a mock of it. It have the same error and working

How can I fix this error showing in console? any advise or answer is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do the following changes in your code :

- remove inputInfo from useEffect dependencies
- instead of using `infoInput.lengthCount` use `infoInput.value.length` to show the length count.

Below is the working code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export function ConditionalInput() {

  const [inputInfo, setInputInfo] = useState({ value: "", lengthCount: 0 });
  const [warningMessageVisible, setWarningMessageVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (inputInfo.value.length > 5) {
      setInputInfo((s) => ({ ...s, lengthCount: 0 }));
    }
  }, [warningMessageVisible]);

  const onChange = ({ target }) => {
    setInputInfo((s) => ({ ...s, value: target.value }));
    if (target.value.length > 5) {
      setWarningMessageVisible(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={inputInfo.value} onChange={onChange} />
      <div>Number of secrets: {inputInfo.value.length}</div>
      {warningMessageVisible && (
        <h3>Limit Exceeds (only upto 5 characters accepted)</h3>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Got it. It isn't the exact solution I wanted but It did solved the problem I was facing . It didn't come to my mind that I can just use .length() instead of having a new state poperty for storing the length.  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of the dependencies array you've added `setInputInfo` Your useEffect will trigger whenever there is a change in the `inputInfo`. And inside the useEffect you're modifying the `inputInfo`. So basically it's creating an infinite loop which will keep rendering the view.

To fix that you can remove `inputInfo` from the dependency array of your useEffect.

Comment: by removing it count is not showing here ```Number of secrets: {inputInfo.lengthCount}```. It always stays 0

Comment: You can try using a custom function to update the number state.

Answer (score 1):

This issue happen from this `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (inputInfo.value.length > 5) {
    setInputInfo((s) => ({ ...s, lengthCount: 0 }));
  }
}, [inputInfo, warningMessageVisible]);
```

This useEffect alway run when `inputInfo` change. So you need to remove the `inputInfo` at this `useEffect` like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (inputInfo.value.length > 5) {
    setInputInfo((s) => ({ ...s, lengthCount: 0 }));
  }
}, [warningMessageVisible]);
```

Comment: on removing ```inputInfo``` from depency , count is not increasing here ```Number of secrets: {inputInfo.lengthCount}```. It always stays 0

Comment: So you need to separate it to another state. 1 state for value and 1 state for counter